# sending key-pair array object using ajax in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, json, ajax, object

I am trying to send a key-pair based array object using ajax, here array is created dynamically

```
["{\"key\":\"#c1\",\"value\":\"g1\"}","{\"key\":\"#c1\",\"value\":\"g2\"}",   "{\"key\":\"#c2\",\"value\":\"g3\"}", "{\"key\":\"#c4\",\"value\":\"g4\"}"]
```

Above is json formatted data which i am sending to a method and able to receive it. At c# end `Dictionary<string, string> Columns` is used. problem here is that the key values are just number and values contain each element of above mentioned json data as shown below,

```
 foreach(var eachVals in  columns)
 {
     string k = eachVals.Key;
     string col = eachVals.Value;

 }
```

when iterating the dictionary eachVals.key is array index (0,1,...) and eachVals.Value contains `{"key":"#c1","value":"g1"}`
So what i want is separate keys i.e `"#c1","#c1","#c2"...` and values i.e `"g1","g2"...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to deserialize the values from col. Using Newtonsoft.Json, would look something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, string> columns = new Dictionary<string, string>
        {
            { @"0", @"{""key"": ""#c1"", ""value"":""g1"" }" },
            { @"1", @"{""key"": ""#c2"", ""value"":""g2"" }" }
        };

        var result = columns.ToDictionary(
                                column => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(column.Value).key, 
                                column => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<MyObj>(column.Value).value);
```

Where MyObj is:

```
internal class MyObj
{
    public string key { get; set; }
    public string value { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do or get the idea from this:

```
foreach(var eachVals in columns)
 {
     var e = eachVals.Value.Split(',');
     e = e[0].Split(':');
     string k = e[0];
     string v = e[1];
 }
```